# How can I tell IIS to compile specific folders independently of the rest of my Web site?

Tags: asp.net, compiler-construction

Is there any way to get ASP.Net to compile different folders independently?

I have a Web app that uses some commercial software.  The admin UI for this software is in a single folder -- there are about a 1,000 files in there, all told.  (I've looked through it -- it ain't the greatest code ever written...)

This folder takes *forever* to build.  If I build explicitly, it...slowly...compiles..subfolder...after...subfolder...  If I do the site as a Web site project (as opposed to a Web application project -- so no explicit build), I have waited up to *four or five minutes* to refresh a page on a simple code change.

Sometimes it just gets stuck -- I'll be waiting and waiting and I'll just hit F5 for giggles, and -- bam! -- there it is.  It apparently compiled sometime in the last 10 minutes but forgot to tell the browser about it...

How do I get this folder out of the general compilation?  I never change anything in here, and I wish ASP.Net would just compile the friggin' thing to an assembly and *leave it alone.*

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`aspnet_compiler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(VS.80).aspx) to precompile the application? It **does** work on Web site projects as well as Web application projects and it can precompile almost everything in an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too obvious, but... Pull out that folder and create a separate website project for it with its own web.config.

You definitely can't have IIS treat the folders differently without that... it's the ASP.NET engine that handles the on-the-fly compilation, IIS knows nothing about it.